# Spool Over Quota. Queue or Topic endpoint limit exceeded - Solace 3560 Message Router Appliance

Tags: solace, solace-mq

I am getting the following error while trying to publish a message on `Solace Box`:

> Spool Over Quota. Queue or Topic endpoint limit exceeded

Note : I have checked all 3 level of `Quota` (Endpoint/MessageVPN/Appliance) but everything is under assigned quota.

Answer (score 3):

This error message means that the message that the application is trying to publish would cause a queue or topic endpoint to exceed its quota. For example, the endpoint could be under the assigned quota by 50 kB but if the message is over 50 kB, you will see this error message. The next sentence in the error message should specify the name of the topic that the message is being published to.

Verify that every queue or topic endpoint that contains this topic subscription is under the configured maximum quota for that queue or topic endpoint. If spooling the message will cause the spool usage of any of these individual endpoints to go over the maximum quota, the message is rejected with the error message you have provided.

If the topic is in the format `#P2P/QUE/[queueName]`, then the application is publishing messages directly to the that queue. In this case, you should check that specific queue to make sure that the message you are publishing will not cause the queue's spool usage to go over quota.

Comment: I am able to publish message on Queue but not on Topic which were associated with same queue, Please advise.

Comment: There is likely another queue or topic endpoint which contains this same topic subscription that is near the max quota.